# Cannot Remote Desktop to a Win 7 box: how to know which firewall rule and/or policy is causing a packet drop?

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-desktop, remote

I tried everything I could but still cannot remote desktop to a laptop running Win 7 at home.

Basically, I made sure rule exists for TCP 3389 connections to be allowed, no local policies restrict it, etc, but still no luck, System|Remote enables it, all kinds of connections are accepted, etc etc: firewall log shows

... DROP TCP ... 3389 ... RECEIVE

I cannot telnet into that port from the same client box I'm trying to RD from.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: How can be known which exact firewall rule or policy is being applied to decide to reject a packet? Is that info contained somewhere?

Comment: Can you connect to it from within your own network? Is it set to require network level authentication?

Comment: Are you connecting from work? if so they could have a firewall that is blocking that port outgoing

Comment: Client and server are connected to my same home LAN. For some reason (either a policy or a firewall rule that is taken precendence over the RD one), connection attempt to 3389 is getting blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall log holds the answer:

> ... DROP TCP ... 3389 ... RECEIVE

It looks to me like the firewall is dropping the incoming RDP connection.

Comment: Sure... my question is why that's happening :-)

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand... "Why is is happening?" Because it's being blocked by the firewall. Take another look at the firewall rules. It may be that the firewall rule is set to be a private network rule and not a public network rule.

Comment: That's what I'm saying... there's a rule enabling Remote Desktop for public, home/work and domain network profiles, still connection attempt is being dropped...

Comment: Well, I fixed it... my home network was being set as Public in my server box. Set it to Home and worked. What's confusing is that my firewall rule enabling RD was for all profiles... Thanks.

Comment: That is strange, glad you figured it out.